# Rails NoMethodError for Blog#create on Heroku, but not Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app with a basic blog structure.  Creating new blogs works perfectly on `localhost`, but when I try to create a new blog on Heroku I get the following error in my logs:

```
2018-07-11T21:20:01.863867+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0] Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/819c55b783715f61a2656207b4852b5c20180711-4-140ohfr.jpg'
2018-07-11T21:20:01.872443+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-07-11T21:20:01.873180+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0]
2018-07-11T21:20:01.873253+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0] NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass):
2018-07-11T21:20:01.873285+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0]
2018-07-11T21:20:01.873329+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0] app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:48:in `create'
2018-07-11T21:20:01.874027+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.219.132 - - [11/Jul/2018:21:19:56 UTC] "POST /blogs HTTP/1.1" 500 1958
2018-07-11T21:20:01.874063+00:00 app[web.1]: http://www.linchpinrealty.com/blogs/new -> /blogs
2018-07-11T21:20:01.874816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/blogs" host=www.linchpinrealty.com request_id=2f20a9d7-e0f6-4ab9-b2ac-d6b3a08e8ed0 fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5463ms status=500 bytes=2235 protocol=http
```

My `blogs#create` method is decently simple:

```
 def create
    @pillars = Pillar.all
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    if current_user.id = 1
      @blog.user_id = 2
    else
      @blog.user = current_user
    end

    if @blog.save
      redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And I have the following permissions:

```
 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :teaser, :body, :user_id, :image, :tag_list, :link_text, :link_filename, :pillars_id)
    end
```

I'm not sure where things are going off the rails (no pun intended).  I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696270/nomethoderror-on-heroku-but-not-locally) question where the issue was a database issue.  In which case, the only recent change I've made would be in my `blogs#show` method...even though I have no idea how that would prevent a blog from even saving in the database (which it doesn't):

```
  def show
    @pillars = Pillar.all
    @pillar = Pillar.find_by(id: @blog.pillars_id)
    @related = Blog.where(pillars_id: @blog.pillars_id).where.not(id: @blog.id).limit(4)
    @comment = @blog.comments.build
    @comments = Comment.where(blog_id: @blog.id, approved: true)
    if current_user
      @user = current_user
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: hard to tell what went wrong, `undefined method []= for nil:NilClass` suggests assignment on nil object. What line is `app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:48`?

Comment: @kasperite line 48 is my `@blog = Blog.new(blog_params)`, which is why I included my params in the OP.  Sorry that wasn't clearer...

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with `image` then since you said it works fine locally?

Comment: @kasperite Oh no. I just upgraded to rails 5 and the image uploads with paperclip. Is it THAT depreciated already?

Comment: the README said it is but I don't know what your case is like, you may want to consult the migration docs :)

Comment: also `if current_user.id = 1`  is wrong, it should be `if current_user.id == 1`

Comment: @RaviMariya Thank you for pointing this out!  I did fix that issue, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the main issue.

Comment: What are the params being passed? Can you add more logs from before and after the request?

Comment: @KartikeyTanna unfortunately I think kasperite hit on the right idea that paperclip was not valid with rails 5.2.  Tried performing the same action with ActiveStorage but hit on this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314520/console-error-trying-to-do-direct-uploads-with-rails-activestorage-and-amazon-aw

Comment: Without the image is it working fine?

Comment: You could start a `heroku run rails console -a your_app` and try to create a blog manually in the console to debug it better. Are you sure you are not missing a migration?

Comment: @KartikeyTanna No, I get the same error without an image.

Comment: @Derek no, it's actually messed up to the point where a console won't even open.

Comment: you might also try `heroku logs --tail` and then post the output when trying to save a post, after looking at this question and then coming back to it I feel like there is just not enough information here to solve.

Comment: Wow, if you can't even get a rails console working something is seriously wrong. Push up the branch again and see if you have any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs and the fact it's working fine on your localhost, it's probably an error to host your tmp image file.

You should take a look at these articles:

- [Rails Active storage on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku?preview=1)
- [Rails Active storage exemple on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/rails-active-storage)

*Edit:*

I just saw you `get the same error without an image`, but don't you set any default image ?

-> Could you post error logs without uploaded image ?

*Edit2:*

I went on your website, I updated an image on an existing blog post and it works so it's probably not linked to the image system.

***Edit3:***

After some tests on your websites, it's the `tag_list` field which is wrong: you can create some new blog post without tags but as soon as you insert some tags an error is raised.

Ps: Sorry I did not managed to get my tests deleted without routes

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your migrations on Heroku?