# Console error trying to do direct uploads with Rails ActiveStorage and Amazon aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm trying to replace the depreciated (for Rails 5.2) paperclip with image uploads using ActiveStorage and aws s3.  I'm using [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) guide and the GoRails episode on it, but have hit a console error I can't parse.  Everything looks okay on my form, but when I go to submit I get this in my console:

```
activestorage.self-6e8d967adecc8b2a7259df0f51ef5b6f171c33267c7d149a474beccd90c68697.js?body=1:1 POST http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have this on my `blogs#new` _`form.html.erb`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label "Picture" %>
  <%= f.file_field :image, direct_upload: true %>
</div>
```

I put this in my model:

```
has_one_attached :image
```

I have `:image` in my params

```
def blog_params
  params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :teaser, :body, :user_id, :tag_list, :link_text, :link_filename, :pillars_id, :image)
end
```

I added this to my `storage.yml`:

```
Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  region: us-west-1
  bucket: nameofbucket
```

And this in my development environment:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

I included the javascript/css from the RubyOnRails Guides linked above.  Anyone see where this error is coming from?  I'm not too experienced with debugging console errors, so any info or wisdom is appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Here's the error that happens in my Rails Console:

```
LoadError - Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable, expected /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb to define it:

::1 - - [12/Jul/2018:13:56:05 PDT] "POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads HTTP/1.1" 500 7784
http://localhost:3000/blogs/new -> /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads
```

**Other Note**

When I try to create a blog without an image I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: That's from your browser console? If so, what's in your rails console?

Comment: @jvillian Good question!  (Sorry, duh.)  I added that error to the OP as well.

Comment: Did try the googlies with [Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable+to+autoload+constant+ActiveStorage%3A%3ABlob%3A%3AAnalyzable)? It looks like there might be some promising leads there.

Comment: @jvillian I did try the googlies (and am totally stealing that phrase) with that.  There is a lot there, showing this is a common problem, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: So in your gemfile you have something like: `gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false` and ran `bundle update && bundle install` with no success?

Comment: @MarkMerritt Yes, I have `gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false` and `gem 'aws-sdk' , '~> 3'`.  Have updated and installed.

Comment: Hey, can you open your console, type : `ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]` and `ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]` and make sure the variables do not return nil ?

Comment: `rails active_storage:install` & `rake db:migrate`.  Did you run this to setup the storage?

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358427/unable-to-autoload-constant-activestorageblobanalyzable-error-with-rails-5-2